# Python - force window to render below everything else

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, rainmeter, desktop-wallpaper

I'm trying to do basically what [Rainmeter](https://github.com/rainmeter/rainmeter) does, but in Python. Does anyone know how to force my window to be below everything else? (And possibly how to let clicks go through to desktop icons?)

I figure this probably needs some ctypes calls into Windows libraries. Someone pointed me at [SetWindowPos (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos), but I'm not sure how to hook that.

Answer (score 1):

With [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/):

```
import win32con
import win32gui

hwnd = your window handle
win32gui.SetWindowPos(
    hwnd
    , win32con.HWND_BOTTOM
    , 0, 0, 0, 0
    , win32con.SWP_NOSIZE | win32con.SWP_NOACTIVATE | win32con.SWP_NOMOVE
)
```